# Import SSL AWS Certificate Manager - Cannot Import more than one certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I have a EV certificate for multiple subdomains for my website. The list of domains allowed are:

- `cdn.subdomain.mydomain.com`
- `subdomain-staging.mydomain.com`
- `subdomain.mydomain.com`

I want to use a Cloudfront CDN with a custom CNAME as `cdn.subdomain.mydomain.com` and the EV ssl certificate. But whenever I am trying to import it in AWS Certificate manager, I am getting the following error.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

My certificate is like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//CONTENT Intermediate CA Bundle
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//CONTENT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//CONTENT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Ignore the Intermediate CA Bundle and try the first of the other certificate as a sanity check. Does that import ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your file into 3 files by the `-----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE-----` lines. Every file should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXX a lot of base64 data here XXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

For each file use:

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -text -noout
```

You should get a lot of details about each certificate, including which domains it covers, etc. Only one of those certificates should contain your domain. If you have only one, that's the one you should upload to ACM. If you have more than one with your domain, please put the output of the `openssl` command for them here so we can help you figure out why you have more than one. Don't forget to remove the private key, if it's displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error which you are facing is not because of you don't know about how to import SSL certificate in AWS certificate manager but due to you are entering more than one SSL certificate or using  one/same EV SSL certificate for your multiple sub domains.

EV SSL certificate secures only single domain.

So, in this case you have two options:

1. Either purchase separate EV SSL certificate for each domain.
2. Or [go with EV Multi Domain SSL certificate](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-ev-multi-domain-ssl-increases-business-conversion-saves-money-and-time) which provides green bar
   for all your multiple domains. It saves your time used for different
   certificate management & also money.

Or if you still have confusion about how to import SSL certificate in AWS manager then you should refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html

Comment: I have a EV multi Domain SSL only, but its 2 part certificate. That is why its creating an issue.

Comment: 2 part certificate, didn't get you.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the format of my certificate. If this helps

Comment: As per this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/custom-ssl-domain-names-root-domain-hosting-for-amazon-cloudfront/ cloudfront supports multi domain ssl, wildcard ssl, ev ssl etc but not anywhere mentioned that they are supporting ev multi domain ssl certificate so you should have to contact them from here https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/